# What is the difference between nhr and $n+r-1\choose r-1$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am very confused between these two things:
$$n+r-1\choose r$$ and $$n+r-1\choose r-1$$
I am not able to get a intuitive understanding about these.
Please help

Comment: The difference between $\binom{n+r-1}r$ and $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ is $\frac{(n+r-1)!}{(n-1)!(r-1)!}\left(\frac1r-\frac1n\right)$.  What nhr is I don't know, I don't read your notes.

Comment: this is not clear.  $\binom ab$ is the number of subsets of size $b$ in a set of size $a$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Since
$\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}
=\binom{n+r-1}{n}
$,
they are the same thing with
the variables swapped.

Seems to depend on the context.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.